# How do I set up Microsoft Exchange Server 2010?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2010

There are currently 24 computers in our office. There is no network set up at all. We would like to set up an Exchange Server to handle all our email.

Can anybody please give me a step by step on how I could accomplish the same? I have read through countless pages which didn't make much sense to me.

Is it necessary to have a LAN set up to use Exchange? If yes, how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need a LAN.  You also need Active Directory, multiple Windows servers, licensing for Windows, user CALs, Exchange, Exchange CALs (client access licenses).  It's a huge job to implement.  If you could get LAN and internet access, outsource your email to Google.